# How do I exclude a regex value in a replace

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex expression which searches for strings using a Prefix and a Suffix. In it's simplest form `\$\$\w+\$\$` will find `$$My_Name$$` (in this case the Prefix and Suffix are both equal to `$$`) Another example would be `\[\#\w+\#\]` to match `[#My_Name#]`.

The Prefix and Suffix will always be a specific string of 0 to n characters which I can always safely escape for a direct character match.

I extract the Matches in my C# code so I can work with them but obviously my match contains `$$My_Name$$` but what I want is to simply get the inner string between the Suffix and Prefix: `My_Name`.

How do I exclude the Prefix and Suffix from the result?

Comment: @AlanMoore thanks for the edit, it made the question more readable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your REGEX to `\$\$(\w+)\$\$` and use `$1` to get the matching (inner) string.

For example

```
string pattern = @"\$\$(\w+)\$\$";
string input = "$$My_Name$$";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
Match result = rgx.Match(input);
Console.WriteLine(result.Groups[1]);
```

Outputs: `"My Name"`

P.S - There's no need to use explicitly typed local variables, but I just wanted the types to be clear.

Comment: You could also name the group: `@"\$\$(?<varName>\w+)\$\$"` and access it via `Regex.Groups["varName"].Value`, or, for string replacement: `Regex.Replace(@"\$\$(?<varName>\w+)\$\$", input, "${varName}")`.

Comment: @fourpastmidnight is right, but whether you use a named group or a numbered group, there's no need to do a `Replace()`.  Just grab the `Value` property of the appropriate `Group`.

Comment: @Itay your edit brought the answer closer to what I wanted, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can group your `w+` into a group like this `(w+)` then when you retrieve the matched string you might be able to ask for that subgroup.

I do not know if I am wrong (but you didn't provided any code whatsoever) but I think this is how it is done: `.Groups[1].Value` on the the result of `Regex.Match`.

Answer (score 1):

How about the regex below. It works by capturing the first character into a named group then capturing any repeats into a named group called first group which it then uses to match the end of the string. It will work with any number of repeated character so long as they repeated at the end of the word.

```
'(?<first_group>(?<first_char>.)\k<first_char>+)(?<word>\w+)\k<first_group>+'
```

You just need to then extract the capture group named word like so:

```
String sample = "$$My_Name$$";
Regex regex = new Regex("(?<first_group>(?<first_char>.)\k<first_char>+)(?<word>\w+)\k<first_group>+");

Match match = regex.Match(sample);

if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["word"].Value);
}
```

Comment: The prefix and suffix aren't the problem.  He knows exactly what they'll look like and how to escape them.  He just wants to know how to scrape them off and retrieve only what's between them.  In other words, he didn't know about capturing groups.

Answer (score 0):

You can use named group like this:

```
(\$\$)(?<group1>.+?)\1      -- pattern 1  (first  case)
\[(#)(?<group2>.+?)\1\]     -- pattern 2  (second case)
```

or combined representation would be:

```
(\$\$)(?<group1>.+?)\1|\[(#)(?<group2>.+?)\3\]
```

I would suggest you to use `.+?` it will help you to match any character other than your prefix/suffix.

#### [Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/xH3wB7)